# c# - beginner wants to add code on the run from a string containing a math function

Tags: c#

I learned basic algorithms on visual C# in highschool, and I made a simple code that numerically integrates a math function within given limits.

I want to be able to change the function the code integrates without actually editing the code, so I googled it for a while and found a lot of articles about how to do it. I tired to understand it but the problem is I can't understand any of what's written there because it's too much above my level.

I need a code that can add code on the run from a string containing a math function, that can accept a variable, `log`, `ln`, `powers`, `sin`, `cos`, `tan` and maybe `pi` and `e`, that is ready in a friendly "copy-paste" format, followed by instructions on where to paste it, and how to connect it to my code. To clarify:

I want to take something like this:

```
string s = "Sqrt(ln(1 + x ^ 2))";
```

and make it like this:

```
double x = 0;
double y = Math.Sqrt(Math.Log(1 + Math.Pow(x,2)));
```

I know it's a pretty annoying request and if it's not the right place to ask such a thing I apologize in advance.

Comment: ok you need a parse tree. you can start with that.

Comment: That's because this is not beginner problem. @Reed Copsey, gave you your best choice, unless you want to learn, Reflection(Emit), the DLR or how to write your own parser and grammar, first. All interesting stuff, but may be a few simpler problems to work on before you go at this. I could give you a pile of code, it would means as little to you as what you've already found.

Answer (score 11):

This is actually fairly difficult to do in a language like C#, as it's statically compiled.

A good alternative would be to use an expression parsing library, such as [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).  This library would allow you to create the expression (your string), parse it, and extract the result.

Comment: i did stamble upon this... thing. it looked like what I was looking for. I understand it's something like an expansion that adds those expressions, right? how do I implament this?

Comment: @Izabo The project pages have documentation, and samples you can try, etc.  Their manuals will walk you through how this works.